# Button not working in certain parts of my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button `id="getstarted"` located near the top and the bottom of my HTML. The button near the top works, but the one near the bottom does not work. They are formatted exactly the same. I want both buttons to work.

Here is my code.
**edited code. I added `onclick="window.location.href = 'getstarted.html';"` to my buttons. now the first button works, but the second one does not work. how do I get the second button to work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 70) {
      $('#header').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
      $('#header').fadeOut(500);
    }
  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 70) {
      $('#pricing').css("color", "#000");
    } else {
      $('#pricing').css("color", "#FFF");
    }
  });

});

// slideshow
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#laptopslideshop > div:gt(0)").hide();

  setInterval(function() {
    $('#laptopslideshop > div:first')
      .fadeOut(500)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(500)
      .end()
      .appendTo('#laptopslideshop');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 84px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #header {
    height: 60px;
  }
}

#main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(Images/teamchat.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: cover;
}

.headerContents {
  text-align: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
}

.headerpandc {
  margin-right: 18%;
  margin-top: 17px;
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .headerpandc {
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-top: 14px;
  }
}

#pricing {
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  margin-right: 55px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #pricing {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 3%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 355px) {
  #pricing {
    display: none;
  }
}

#pricing:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#pricing:active {
  color: #000;
}

#getstarted {
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  background-color: #5a52ff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  outline: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #getstarted {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

#getstarted:hover {
  background-color: #3d33ff;
}

#getstarted:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
  box-shadow: 0 1px #666;
}

#telosdesignlogo {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #telosdesignlogo {
    margin-left: 4%;
    height: 23px;
  }
}


/*main text*/

#mainbox {
  height: 470px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  left: 28%;
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  color: #FFF;
}

#hitelos {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

#maintext {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 3.5em;
}

#mainpricing {
  z-index: 5;
}


/* Laptop slideshow begins */

#laptopslideshop {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.mySlides {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header"></div>

<div class="headerContents">
  <div class="headerpandc">
    <a id="pricing" href="pricing.html">Pricing</a><button id="getstarted" onclick="window.location.href = 'getstarted.html';">Get Started</button>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/TelosLogo with text.png" href="index.html" alt="TelosDesign" id="telosdesignlogo" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="mainbox">
    <div id="hitelos">
      Hi! We're Telos.
    </div>
    <div id="maintext">
      Beautiful websites tailored to your unique business.
    </div>
    <button id="getstarted" onclick="window.location.href = 'getstarted.html';">Get Started</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="laptopslideshop">
  <div>
    <img class="mySlides" src="Images/laptoppic1test.png" alt="Laptop and Phone" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="mySlides" src="Images/laptoppic2test.png" alt="Laptop and Phone" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` should be unique to an element(just one), use a `class` instead

In your code you use javascript(jquery) to control `href`, not html, see `onclick`.

```
<button id="getstarted" onclick="window.location.href = 'getstarted.html';">
```

The javascript is taking in consideration only the first element because no other element with the same `id` should exist.

--

I see that you have also:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

What this code is doing ?

Check the web browser console for JavaScript errors from other sources/code.

Comment: Why wouldn't a button thats basically a link work because two things have the same id?

Comment: I changed the id to class and the second button is still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check the web browser console for JavaScript errors from other sources/code.

Comment: That is strange because is working for me, and I see also for the other users, so it is something else, like the app.js (that we don't have) that is creating the issue. You need to add all js code.

Answer (score -2):

Try with this code

```html
 <a id="pricing" href="http://google.com">Pricing</a>
 <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><button id="getstarted">Get Started</button></a>
 <a href="index.html">
 <img src="Images/TelosLogo with text.png" href="http://google.com" alt="TelosDesign" id="telosdesignlogo"></a>
```

Comment: Just tried it! It works when I replace the first button, but when I replaced the second button (near the end of my code). The button is still unresponsive